# Why use advanced compiler techniques over simple string manipulation in small compilers?

Tags: string, compiler-construction

What advantage is using (what I understand as) advanced compiler techniques like special grammar, AST, etc over simple string manipulation for making very small programming languages? I'm interested in compiler design and don't know wether I should learn all of this compiler theory if I'm only going to make small and simple languages. I know that as I start to make bigger languages I will probably have to use parser generators and the like, but until then should I bother?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really answerable.  You don't need those techniques until "simple string manipulation" isn't sufficient, and after that the advantage is that you need them.

Comment: Things would work for simple languages and simple compilers. But ultimately you'll need more techniques to make the compiler better.

Comment: The real answer is that for virtually anything which is a "programming language", string manipulation pretty much isn't good enough.  Its kind of like driving nails with your hand:  on really rare occasions it may work, but generally you're really better off with a hammer.

Comment: What "string manipulation" you're talking about? I'm not aware of any "simple" string manipulation technique which would be easier than a trivial parsing-ast transforms-code generation chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely know what an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) is and how to build one. Even if you use parser generators later on. I mean, how can you be interested in compiler design but not in grammar and syntax trees? It always pays off to learn how stuff works under the hood, rather than taking it as magic.

And seriously, parsing anything else than [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) or [Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is awful with string manipulation as soon as it gets more complicated...